# TypeError: $.each is not a function (ReactJS)

Tags: css, reactjs, typeerror, create-react-app

I have a ReactJS (Create-React-App) project. It gets successfully rendered at my localhost when I run the command `npm start` .

But when I run the build command : `npm run build` I get following error:

> yarn run v1.16.0 $ react-scripts build Creating an optimized
>   production build... Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/css/master.css Module build failed: TypeError: $.each is not a
>   function
>
> error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
>   https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
>   command.

But I have not used `$.each` function anywhere in my `master.css`

**master.css**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* for icons */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src:url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), 
    url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.glyphicon {  /*http://getbootstrap.com/components//*/ /* for icon list */
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

/* for refrence icons */
.glyphicon-earphone:before{content:"\e182";
    color:#00429b;
}


.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_tab {
height: 20px;
min-height:20px;}

/* end for icons */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'omnesmedium';
    src:url('../fonts/omnesmedium.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/omnesmedium.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), 
    url('../fonts/omnesmedium.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('../fonts/omnesmedium.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/omnesmedium.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/omnesmedium.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensansregular';
    src:url('../fonts/opensansregular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/opensansregular.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), 
    url('../fonts/opensansregular.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('../fonts/opensansregular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/opensansregular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/opensansregular.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensanssemibold';
    src:url('../fonts/opensanssemibold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/opensanssemibold.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), 
    url('../fonts/opensanssemibold.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('../fonts/opensanssemibold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/opensanssemibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/opensanssemibold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size:100%; 
}
* {
    outline: none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
              box-sizing: border-box;   
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #2e4fa5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #2e4fa5;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;/*auto*/
}
.contentarea {
    max-width: 999px !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.insidebg
{
    background:url(../img/topbg.jpg) repeat-x top #FFFFFF;
    height:135px;
}

.homebg
{
    background:url(../img/homebg.jpg) repeat-x top #0a86ca;
}

.loginbg
{
    background:url(../img/jio_loginbg.jpg) top center;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#0a86ca;
}

.loginarea
{
    width:75%;
    background:url(../img/couple.png) left top no-repeat;
    float:right;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    height:420px;
}

.loginpatch
{
    width:400px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;  
    float:right;
    text-align: center;
    padding:35px;
    margin-top:100px;
    border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
    background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */ 
}
.loginpatch .StoreNo input[type="text"]
{
    font-size: .9em;    
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  

    border:1px solid #e1e4eb;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:10px;
    /*text-indent:35px;*/
    /*padding-left: 45px;*/ 
    margin:10px 0px;
    width:70%;
    color:#787b82;
}
.loginpatch h1
{
    font-size:2em;
    color:#0b81c6;
    font-family:omnesmedium, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}

.txtbox1 
{
    font-size: .9em;    
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    background:url(../img/userid-icon.jpg) left no-repeat;
    border:1px solid #e1e4eb;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:10px;
    /*text-indent:35px;*/
    padding-left: 45px; 
    margin:10px 0px;
    width:100%;
    color:#787b82;
}

.txtbox2
{
    font-size: .9em;    
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:url(../img/password-icon.jpg) left no-repeat;
    border:1px solid #e1e4eb;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:10px;
    /*text-indent:35px;*/
    padding-left: 45px; 
    margin:10px 0px;
    width:100%;
    color:#787b82;  
}

.selectoperator select
{
    font-size: .9em;    
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #e1e4eb;
    color:#000000;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:10px;
    /*text-indent:35px;*/
    margin:10px 0px;
    width:100%;
    color:#787b82;  
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;   
    background:url(../img/arrow-icon.png) 100% center no-repeat;    
}


/*.txtbox3
{
    font-size: .9em;    
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #e1e4eb;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px 0px;
    width:100%;
    color:#787b82;  
}
*/
.loginpatch .goldbutton
{
    padding:.1em;
    font-family:omnesmedium, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#a56d00;
    width:95px;
    border:1px solid #ffb400;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:4px;
    background:url(../img/goldarrow-login.jpg) right 12% center no-repeat #ffc600;
    text-align:center;
}
.loginpatch .goldbuttonPopup
{
    padding:.1em;
    font-family:omnesmedium, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#a56d00;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #ffb400;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:4px;
    background:url(../img/goldarrow-login.jpg) right 1% center no-repeat #ffc600;
    text-align:center;
}
.forgotpasswordtxt
{
    font-family:omnesmedium, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:1em;  
    color:#0b81c6;
    float:right;
    width:150px;
    margin-top:12px;
    text-decoration:none;       
}

.forgotpasswordtxt a
{
    font-family:omnesmedium, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:1em;  
    color:#0b81c6;
    float:right;
    width:150px;
    text-decoration:none;   
}

.forgotpasswordtxt a:hover
{
    font-family:omnesmedium, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:1em;  
    color:#0b81c6;
    float:right;
    width:150px;
    text-decoration:underline;
}


.portaltitle
{
    color:#214497;
    font-family:omnesmedium, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    margin-top:0.6em;   
    text-align:right;       

}

.header
{
    overflow:hidden;
}


.logo
{
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}

.welcomearea
{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}

.yellowbg
{
    background:#ffdd00;
    height:4px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bac5df;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%; 
}
.navbluebg
{
    background:#214497;
    height:55px;
    /*border-bottom:1px solid #bac5df;*/
    width:100%; 
}

.yellowbgPopup
{
    background:#ffdd00;
    height:30px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bac5df;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; 
    color:#214497;
    font-family:-Opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    padding :5px;
    font-weight:bold;

}

.userpic
{
    padding:15px;
    border-left:1px solid #f8f9fb;  
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
}

.storepic
{
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    padding: 24px 0px 24px 0px;
}

.welcometxt
{
    font-family:omnesmedium, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#a1a2a3;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    margin-top:1.6em;   
    text-align:right;
}

.welcometxt a
{
    color:#a1a2a3;
}

.storecodenum
{
    font-family:omnesmedium, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /*font-size:1em;*/
    color:#616671;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:120px;
    margin-top:1.6em;
    float:right;
}
.storecodenum select
{
    font-size: .8em;    
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #e1e4eb;
    color:#000000;
    border-radius:4px;
    /*padding:5px;*/
    /*text-indent:35px;*/
    /*margin:5px 0px;*/
    width:90%;
    color:#787b82;  
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;   
    background:url(../img/arrow-icon.png) 90% right no-repeat;  
}
.storecodenum input[type="text"]
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    /*padding:10px;*/
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.8em;
    /*margin:10px 0px;  
    margin-left:.8em;*/
    color:#787b82;
    border:1px solid #edd995;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:6px;
    width:110px;    
}
.navigation
{
    text-align:center;
}

.bredcrum
{
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#7f848f;
    margin:10px 0;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;   
}

.bredcrum a
{
    color:#214497;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;   
}

.bredcrum a:hover
{
    color:#214497;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:underline;      
}

.yellowtable
{
    background-color:#fffdf6;
    border-top:1px solid #f9f0d0;
    border-left:1px solid #f9f0d0;
    border-right:1px solid #f9f0d0; 
    border-bottom:2px solid #f9f0d0;            
    padding:15px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;   
}

.yellowline
{
    background-color:#fffdf6;
    border-top:1px solid #f9f0d0;
    /* border-left:1px solid #f9f0d0;
    border-right:1px solid #f9f0d0; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #f9f0d0;             */

}

.yellowtxt
{
    font-family:opensanssemibold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color:#a6881e;
    font-size:1.2em;
    text-align:center;  
    font-weight:normal;
    width:100%;
}

.yellowtable input[type="text"]
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding:.6em;
    font-family:calibribold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin-right:.8em;
    color:#656565;
    width:250px;
    border:1px solid #edd995;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
}

.yellowtable .bluebutton
{
    background:#0081c5;
    padding:.6em;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin-right:.8em;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #3974b9;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
}

.yellowtable .redbutton
{
    background:#e0252c;
    padding:.6em;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin-right:.8em;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #bd1515;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
}

.tablelist
{
    text-align:center;
    float:0 auto;
    margin:1em 0 0 0;
}

.tablelist .blueeditbutton
{
    padding:.6em;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    margin-right:.8em;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:80px;
    border:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:4px;
    background:url(../img/edit-icon.jpg) left 10% center no-repeat #0081c5; 
}

.tablelist .blueeditbuttonLarge
{
    padding:.6em;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    margin-right:.8em;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:110px;
    border:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:4px;
    background:url(../img/edit-icon.jpg) left 10% center no-repeat #0081c5; 
}


.tablelist .greydeletebutton
{
    padding:.6em;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    margin-right:.8em;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:80px;
    border:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:4px;
    background:url(../img/delete-icon.jpg) left 10% center no-repeat #7b818f;
    text-indent:10px;
}

.tablelist .greybuttonActCode
{
    padding:.6em;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    margin-right:.8em;
    color:#ffffff;
    border:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:4px;
    background:url(../) left 10% center no-repeat #7b818f;
    text-indent:10px;
}

.tabletype2
{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #f9f0d0;
    padding:0;
    margin-top: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    /*height:100%;*/
}

.tabletype2 table
{
    padding:10px;
    /*height: 910px;*/
    }

.tabletype2 table tr
{
    padding:10px;
    border-top:1px solid #fbf3d7;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fbf3d7;
}

.tabletype2 .title
{
    color:#a6881e;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:800;
    background:#fffdf6;
    border-right:1px solid #f9f0d0;
    width: 25%; 
}

.tabletype2 input[type="text"]
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin:10px 0px;    
    margin-left:.8em;
    color:#787b82;
    border:1px solid #edd995;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
    width:80%;  
}
.mytable input[type="text"]
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:10px 0px;    
    margin-left:.8em;
    color:#787b82;
    border:1px solid #edd995;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
    width:100px;    
}
.tabletype2 .smallInput input[type="text"]
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin:10px 0px;    
    margin-left:.8em;
    color:#787b82;
    border:1px solid #edd995;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
    width:130px;    
}
.tabletype2 input[type="password"]
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin:10px 0px;    
    margin-left:.8em;
    color:#787b82;
    border:1px solid #edd995;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
    width:80%;  
}

.tabletype2 select
{
    font-size: .9em;    
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:1px solid #edd995;
    color:#787b82;
    border-radius:8px;
    padding:8px;
    /*text-indent:35px;*/
    margin:10px 0px;    
    margin-left:.8em;
    width:80%;
    color:#787b82;  
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;   
    background:url(../img/selectarrow.jpg) 100% center no-repeat;       
}

.tabletype2 select option
{
    padding-left:10px;
}
 .chkBoxList1 td
{
    width:35%;

    border-right:1px solid #fbf3d7;
}
.box
{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}

.box h3
{
    color:#214497;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em; 
}

.genbutton
{
    background:#0081c5;
    padding:.6em;
    font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.8em;
    margin-right:.8em;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #3974b9;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:8px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.testCssStyle {
    color: #1f5ca9;
    background-color: #c5d4e6;
    table-layout: auto;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-right: gray thin solid;
    border-top: gray thin solid;
    border-left: gray thin solid;
    border-bottom: gray thin solid;
}

.fl-left {
    float: left;
}
.sch-btn {
    width: 68px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.bcol-white {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
.btn-blue {
    background: #0081c5;
    padding: .6em;
    font-family: opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .8em;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #3974b9;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.lbl-txt-1 {
    font-family: humnst777, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding: 10px;
}
.txt-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.fl-right {
    float: right;
}
.hiddencol {
    display: none;
}
div.scrollmenu {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
/* added by chandrani */
.loadingcc{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 10px solid #e74c3c;
    position: relative;
    animation: a1 2s linear infinite;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .loadingcc::before,.loadingcc::after{
    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .loadingcc::before{
    border-top: 10px solid #e67e22;
    transform: rotate(120deg);
  }

  .loadingcc::after{
    border-top: 10px solid #3498db;
    transform: rotate(240deg);
  }

  .loadingcc span{
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    animation: a2 2s linear infinite;
  }

  @keyframes a1 {
    to{
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes a2 {
    to{
      transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
  }
/* end   */

.w-30 {width:30%;float:left;display:block;margin-right:10px;}
.box-100 {width:100%;float:left;display:block;padding:5px;}
.ajax__calendar_container {border: 1px solid #646464;background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000;}
.ajax__calendar_container table thead tr td {font-size:11px !important;padding:0px !important;color:#000000 !important;border-left:none !important;border-right:none !important;background-color:#ffffff !important;}
.editdate tbody td {font-size:11px !important;padding:0px !important;color:#000000 !important;border-left:none !important;border-right:none !important;background-color:#ffffff !important;}
.tbl-bb {font-size:16px !important;}
.mt1 {margin-top:1px;}
.mt4 {margin-top:4px;}
.tblbg {background-color:transparent; border-style:none;}
.bw0{border-width:0px}
.mr-10{margin-right:10px}
.whitespace{white-space:nowrap;}
.fade.show{opacity: 1;}
.col-red{color:#ff0000;}
.text-center{text-align:center;}
.mtb10{margin:10px auto;}
.tbl-global{margin:auto;width:100%;}
.tbl-global thead th td{padding:5px;}
.tbl-global tbody tr td{padding:5px;}
.tabletype2 textarea{background:#FFFFFF;padding:10px;font-family:opensansregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:.8em;margin:10px 0px;margin-left:.8em;color:#787b82;border:1px solid #edd995;-webkit-appearance: none;border-radius:8px;width:80%;}
.tab-menu{background-color:transparent !important;padding: inherit !important;border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f0d0 !important;position:inherit !important;}
.nav-tabs>li>a.active, .nav-tabs>li>a.active:hover, .nav-tabs>li>a.active:focus{border:1px solid #f9f0d0;border-bottom-color:transparent;background-color:#ffffff;}
label{font-weight:normal;}
.ml-10{margin-left:10px !important;}
.tabletype2 .title{font-size:.8em;width:16%;    }
/*End New Class Added by Krishna*/
/*.pie {
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(../PIE.htc);
}*/
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-express-tutorial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jquery": "^1.12.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.13",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-bell-icon": "^1.0.0",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-global-configuration": "^1.3.0",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.2.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT= 3006 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not ie <= 11",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
//import {BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';


import Login from './components/Login.js';
import Default from'./components/Default.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Route path="/Default" component={Default}/>

        <Router >
      <Switch>
        {/* chandrani */}
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
      </Switch>
      </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default withRouter(App);
```

**helper.jsx** where I have used jQuery:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../css/style.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
import BellIcon from 'react-bell-icon';

export function reusecompdidmount() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").attr("autocomplete", "off");
        $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):gt(4)').hide();
        $('.next').click(function() {
            if ($('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):visible:last').is(':last-child')) {
                return false;
            }

            var currentIndex = $('.nav-list').children('li:not(ul li ul li):visible:last').index(),
    nextIndex = currentIndex + 6;
            console.log("currentIndex " + currentIndex + " nextIndex" + nextIndex);
            $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li)').hide();
            $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):lt(' + nextIndex + '):gt(' + currentIndex + ')').show("slide", 500);
        });
        $('.prev').click(function() {
            if ($('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):visible:first').is(':first-child')) {
                return false;
            }

            var currIndex = $('.nav-list').children('li:not(ul li ul li):visible:first').index(),
    prevIndex = currIndex - 6;
            $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li)').hide();
            if (prevIndex < 0) {
                $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):lt(' + currIndex + ')').show("slide", 500);
            } else {
                $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):lt(' + currIndex + '):gt(' + prevIndex + ')').show("slide", 500);
            }
        });
    });
  }

  export function slider(){
      const $ = require("jquery");
      require("jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-slide");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").attr("autocomplete", "off");
        $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):gt(4)').hide();
        $('.next').click(function() {
            if ($('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):visible:last').is(':last-child')) {
                return false;
            }

            var currentIndex = $('.nav-list').children('li:not(ul li ul li):visible:last').index(),
    nextIndex = currentIndex + 6;
            //console.log("currentIndex01 " + currentIndex + " nextIndex" + nextIndex);
            $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li)').hide();
            $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):lt(' + nextIndex + '):gt(' + currentIndex + ')').show("slide", 500);
        });
        $('.prev').click(function() {
            if ($('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):visible:first').is(':first-child')) {
                return false;
            }

            var currIndex = $('.nav-list').children('li:not(ul li ul li):visible:first').index(),
    prevIndex = currIndex - 6;
            $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li)').hide();
            if (prevIndex < 0) {
                $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):lt(' + currIndex + ')').show("slide", 500);
            } else {
                $('.nav-list li:not(ul li ul li):lt(' + currIndex + '):gt(' + prevIndex + ')').show("slide", 500);
            }
        });
    });
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $.each is a JQuery method. Make sure to install jquery

Comment: I have already installed jquery.

Comment: @Kassa check my package.json

Comment: What's your `index.js` and `App.js` look like?

Comment: @Clarity updated those in question.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can think of is that bootstrap import in your `index.js`. Try to change it to:

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Also you might need to add bootstrap's JS as well: `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';`

Edit: Another issue might be that you have more than one instance of jQuery imported. So remove all of them except the top level one (especially those inline ´require´ imports), i think bootstrap or jquery-ui might pull jQuery themselves, so in that case you don't need to include it at all.

Comment: What if you remove all bootstrap imports, does it still happen?

Comment: Ok, how are you importing `master.css`?

Comment: import '../css/master.css';

Comment: Can you add the file where you import it to the question?

Comment: added the file where I used JQuery.

Comment: tried your updated solution,still getting same error.